# Handy c functions that work well with ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, ctypes, libc, loadlibrary

I encountered an example using `rand()` from libc, via ctypes' `LoadLibrary`, where it allows faster random number generation than Python's `random.random` module.

I find it intriguing, since ctypes is in Python's standard library, and I am aware that every OS has some kind of "libc" C standard library module lying around.

However, I'm not very familiar with the C standard library or ctypes.

I was wondering if someone is perhaps using or is aware of specific libc functions, that work well using ctypes, and can boost python tasks with little risk or oddities.

Comment: `rand` is terrible. Don't use it.

Comment: To clarify, many libc `rand` implementations are a simple [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Python's `random` module is based on [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). It's not a reasonable comparison in general.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. What would you recommend from libc though?

Comment: The C standard library is relatively low-level, and you're already using it extensively for CPython's core and extension modules. Also, in Python 3.5+ `ctypes.util.find_library('c')` doesn't work on Windows, so you would have to hard code either the name of a [CRT API set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-extension-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0dll) or the base "ucrtbase.dll" library, but this doesn't even have some common functions such as `printf` but instead internal functions such as `__stdio_common_vfprintf` that are called by statically linked libs.